# How to create test data for dynamic query

Tags: soql

I am using Database.query to query Opportunity records in apex class.

```
list<Opportunity> opplist = Database.query('select Name,createdDate, Billing_Account__c,New_Type__c From Opportunity where id =: oppId');
```

We are creating an App for our clients production environment. And they all have the following fields already present in there production environment. If i will also create the following fields in my developer org then this will cause the duplicate because the client environment already has the fields and after installing the package there will 2 fields for the same purpose which is not a good practice. So that's why i am developing the dynamic query such that when i install the package my code refer to there production fields dynamically. I have written the dynamic query but not able to cover through test class.

Comment: your question is not clear what you are trying to do. you are saying that you are creating a managed package it means you want to put your package in app exchange correct? if it is not you are trying to migrate your dev apex class to your PROD org, if that is case it is not good idea to create fields directly in PROD. you should add those fields in your dev environment. another thing I am unable to understand why you will get get duplicate field error? Please update your question with specific details.

Comment: We are creating an App for our clients production environment. And they all have the following fields already present in there production environment. If i will also create the following fields in my developer org then this will cause the duplicate because the client environment already has the fields and after installing the package there will 2 fields for the same purpose which is not a good practice. So that's why i am developing the dynamic query such that when i install the package my code refer to there production fields dynamically

Answer (score 1):

You can use Schema.getGlobalDescribe to get all fields of any object and prepare your soql statement as shown below

```
String obj = 'Opportunity';

Map<String,Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 
Schema.SObjectType sobjType = gd.get(obj); 
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult describeResult = sobjType.getDescribe(); 
Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> fieldsMap = describeResult.fields.getMap(); 

List<String> fields = new List<String>();

for(Schema.SObjectField sfield : fieldsMap.values())
{
    schema.describefieldresult dfield = sfield.getDescribe();
    //Create list of fields
    fields.add(dfield.getname());
}


List<Opportunity> opplist = database.query('select ' + String.join(fields,',') + 
' from Opportunity');
```

Comment: This works in live code. But when we are calling this from test class how will it cover the dynamic query field values. Because after dynamic query we testing the values like this :-  if(null != opplist[0].get('New_Con__c') && opplist[0].get('Product_Cat__c') != 'ProductNew'){  ....... How the New_Con__c  field will get the value from the test class because it is not present in our org.

Answer (score 0):

if code coverage is important for you then you can use Test.isRunningTest and create the required data in the class itself before the condition check